# ItunesConnectPeople is not submitting app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I uploaded my app via `Application loader` but i no build option("+") is activate on Portal. I have tried 4 , 5 times but same result.

I am facing this problem  in just 1 app although i can submit others app.

Comment: Check in Prerelease tab what is the status of your uploaded app..

Comment: just wait in 2 or 4 hr after that u check the option "build" it surely comes

Comment: If it does not come up within 2 or 4 hrs, check your email that is connected to itunesConnect. They will email you regarding the error.

Comment: increase build number(not version number) and upload again. you get it.

Comment: Thanks Leena.. I check Pre-release. Its Showing "Invalid binary status".

Comment: @iosaddict upload the new binary with incremented bundle version